# pretty url not working on laravel5.2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, pretty-urls

It seems that pretty URLs are not working for me. I have tried every thing I know, when you try `http://wasamar.com.ng/login` it gives a response of **404 Not Found** but `http://wasamar.com.ng/inde.php/login` is ok, I have edited my public/ directory's **.htaccess** file to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName wasamar.com.ng

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wasamar/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the root directory of your Apache virtual host?

Comment: Where can i check that? Is it the /etc/apache2 you are talking about?

Comment: Depends on your OS, eg `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` for Debian.

Comment: Ubuntu server 16.04 yes it is the /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Comment: So ... What is the root directory of your Apache virtual host?

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: That's the vhost file.  I am asking what the docroot is configured as.  Add the content of your conf file to the question.

Comment: Ooh!!! Is that the apache2.conf file in the /etc/apache2/ folder?

Comment: No.  Your vhost config file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`) should include a line something like `DocumentRoot /var/www/...something` - that is what I'm asking about.  What is it?

Comment: Let me update you. 10%

Comment: Looks OK. I guess that `/var/www/html/wasamar/public` is really the `public/` directory of your Laravel project, and `.htaccess` is there.  Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?  Type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i have enabled it since but the issue still exits.

Comment: @Don'tPanic would it be because i installed phpmyadmin (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04) in the server and some config with Apache.conf was done that is affecting the pretty url from working? http://wasamar.com.ng/phpmyadmin

Comment: @Don'tPanic i am having issues on this when i added ssl to it, on another server and i have to the config [issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831722/pretty-urls-not-working-laravel-5-2-on-a-https-protocol) visit [Website](http://wasamar.com.ng/login)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your apache rewrite module is not enabled. To enable the rewrite module on a Ubuntu machine:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If `a2enmod` is not available on your platform, you need to open up your httpd.conf file and uncomment the line including `rewrite_module`. That's something like this on a macOS machine:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then you need to restart the service.

Also, for htaccess files to be effective you need to set `AllowOverride` directive to `All`. Here's an example:

```
<Directory "/absolute/path/to/webserver/root">
    # ...

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    # ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: i have done this  ***sudo a2enmod rewrite*** but still the issue still exits.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for the support but i saw my error, in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file i did not add the `AllowOverride All` section the dirctory tags, when i fixed that it worked.

Comment: Yeah to some extent, you said .htaccess but i fixed it in the .apache2.conf file.

Comment: No, I didn't. To quote: *`for htaccess files to be effective you need to set AllowOverride directive to All.`*.

Comment: Yeah you did, but you forgot to state the file to fix the error.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I supposed it's clear since it's only configurable in the main configuration file.